# Javascript Autoplay but pause on hover

Tags: javascript, hover, slider, autoplay

I'm new to JavaScript & I created a Slider. Now I want to auto-play it and pause it on hover (I'm using WP and Elementor). can you help me?

```
<script>
( function() {
  var the_timer = setInterval( function() {
      if( typeof Swiper && typeof jQuery ) {
          runTheCode();
          clearInterval( the_timer );
      }
  }, 100 );
} )();
function runTheCode() {
    // add 'swiper-container' class to .elementor-container
    jQuery( '.custom-swiper > .elementor-container' ).addClass( 'swiper-container' );
    // add 'swiper-wrapper' class to .elementor-row
    jQuery( '.custom-swiper .swiper-container > .elementor-row' ).addClass( 'swiper-wrapper' );
    // add 'swiper-slide' class to each column
    jQuery( '.custom-swiper .swiper-wrapper > div' ).addClass( 'swiper-slide' );
    // previous & next 
    jQuery( '.custom-swiper .swiper-container' ).append( '<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>' ).append( '<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>' );
    // pagination
    jQuery( '.custom-swiper .swiper-container' ).append( '<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>' );
    
    var swiper = new Swiper('.custom-swiper > .elementor-container', {
    
    
      loop: true, 
      parallax: true,
      speed: 500, 
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
      /*
      pagination: {
        el: '.custom-swiper .swiper-pagination', 
        type: 'bullets', 
        clickable: true, 
      },
      */
    });
};

</script>
```

My CSS (in a Elementor container): I already tried out a few things, but it seems I cannot figure it out.

```
.custom-swiper .elementor-container .elementor-row {
    /flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.custom-swiper > .elementor-container > .elementor-row > .elementor-element.elementor-column {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150vh;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this property to the Swiper constructor :

```
  autoplay: {
    delay: 2500,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  }
```

and you could add `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events to your swiper element,like so (experiment a little yourself) :

HTML

```
<div id="your-swiper-element" onmouseover="stopSwiper()" onmouseout="startSwiper()">
```

JS

```
function startSwiper(){
swiper.autoplay.start();
}

function stopSwiper(){
swiper.autoplay.stop();
}
```